# Apache Flink deployment in Kubernetes - availability & scalability

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I use Kubernetes (`Openshift`) to deploy many microservices. I wish to utilise the same to deploy some of my Flink jobs. `Flink` jobs are critical - some jobs are stateless that process every data (exactly once), some jobs are stateful that looks for patterns in the stream or react to time. No jobs can tolerate long downtime or frequent shutdown (due to programming errors, the way Flink quits).

I find docs mostly lean to deploy Flink jobs in k8s as `Job Cluster`. But how should one take a practical approach in doing it?

- Though k8s can restart the failed Flink `pod`, how can Flink restore its state to recover?
- Can the Flink `pod` be replicated more than one? How do the `JobManager` & `TaskManager` works when two or more pods exists? If not why? Other approaches?

Answer (score 2):

> Though k8s can restart the failed Flink pod, how can Flink restore its state to recover?

From Flink Documentation we have:

> Checkpoints allow Flink to recover state and positions in the streams to give the application the same semantics as a failure-free execution.

It means that you need to have a **Check Storage** mounted in your pods to be able to recover the state.

In **Kubernetes** you could use [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes) to share the data across your pods.

Actually there are a lot of supported plugins, see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes).

You can have more replicas of `TaskManager`, but in Kubernetes you don't need to take care of HA for `JobManager` since you can use Kubernetes **self-healing** deployment.

To use *self-healing* deployment in Kubernetes you just need to create a deployment and set the `replica` to `1`, like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Finally, you can check this links to help you setup Flink in Kubernetes:

[running-apache-flink-on-kubernetes](https://jobs.zalando.com/en/tech/blog/running-apache-flink-on-kubernetes/)

[Flink Job cluster on Kubernetes](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-container/kubernetes)

[Flink Kubernetes Deployments](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html)

[Running Flink on Kubernetes with KUDO](https://flink.apache.org/news/2019/12/09/flink-kubernetes-kudo.html)

Comment: This is not really true. You can have multiple JobManagers at any time, only one of them will be a leader, but You can have as many as You technically want.

Comment: @DominikWosiński yes, you are right! What I mean is in Kubernetes you don't need to care about HA for `JobManager`. The [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/ops/jobmanager_high_availability.html) say you could use standby replicas, but in Kubernetes is not necessary. I've updated my answer.

Comment: So, the job-cluster mode has necessary Flink & the job logic are deployed as a from a single image. If needed, I can configure more than one `TaskManager` within the specific image. Do scaling the pods more than 1 instance effect the job logic (stateful & stateless jobs)? Does increasing the pod means `scale`?

Comment: The `JobManager` will manage the checkpoints, reading the state from persistent volume. Increasing the `replicas` number means increase the number of containers running in parallel, this is the `scale`.

Comment: If I scale the pod, how does the state full jobs behave? Say, the job reads from a kafka topic, partitions the message by its 'status' property and writes the message to a file every 10 minutes.

Comment: Flink uses the checkpoint in a configurable interval to control processed data, doesn't matter if your pods scale up or down. See [here](https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html). I encourage you to test your jobs in [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/) to see the behavior before go to production a